see the security holes of a homemade keygen using python
I made my own desktop application keygen with python programming language with the system apply lic file to open the license, I want to know for friends who understand the real crack what they skip whether modifying the lic file or directly cutting the if alse path from the license and how can I strengthen it again, I am still learning in cracking software to find out what they cut, please advise her
knowing the loopholes of the self-made keygen
